# How to include .ODG graphs when using org-latex-export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, images, inline-image

How do I include `.odg` files (created by libreoffice-draw) as a figure when exporting org file into PDF file?

And, also is it possible to make `odg` work with `M-x org-toggle-inline-images`?

Comment: You can use LO to export it as PDF instead. Or use the command described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76054978/code-or-command-line-for-converting-odg-open-document-graphic-to-png-jpeg-et) to convert to JPG/PNG. Those can be included in LaTeX with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NickD commented, we can convert `.odg` file with source block execution,
and use the output as image file.

For example, I have `"asdf.odg"` file, then can export and insert `jpg` with
following:

```org
#+begin_src shell :results file :exports results
soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard \
        --norestore  --convert-to \
        jpg:draw_jpg_Export \
        "asdf.odg"\
        --outdir /tmp/ \
        > /tmp/conversion_exec_output.log.txt
echo -n /tmp/asdf.jpg
#+end_src
```

```org
#+RESULTS:
[[file:/tmp/asdf.jpg]]
```